# google maps polyline connected with dots/circles

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

[image]

As you can see in screenshot there are 2 circles connected with polyline. How can I achieve this? How it is called?

I have tried using markers with icon but when I zoom in my icon is also zooming in and became smaller.
Here is the code I tried:

```
private void addMarker(LatLng position){

        int height = 50;
        int width = 50;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_blue_for_marker);
        Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(position);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker));
        options.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
        mMap.addMarker(options);
    }
```

EDIT:
Before zooming:
[image]

After zooming[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the issue is not with marker itself - it size didn't change while zooming. For example with marker drawable `ic_blue_circle.xml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="496.158dp"
        android:height="496.158dp"
        android:viewportWidth="496.158"
        android:viewportHeight="496.158">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#0000FF"
        android:pathData="M496.158,248.085c0-137.021-111.07-248.082-248.076-248.082C111.07,0.003,0,111.063,0,248.085 c0,137.002,111.07,248.07,248.082,248.07C385.088,496.155,496.158,385.087,496.158,248.085z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M351.08,248.083c0-56.891-46.115-103.002-103-103.002c-56.886,0-103.002,46.111-103.002,103.002 c0,56.881,46.116,102.996,103.002,102.996C304.965,351.079,351.08,304.964,351.08,248.083z" />
</vector>
```

and code like:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    List<LatLng> sourcePoints = new ArrayList<>();

    addCircleMarker(new LatLng(49.182856, -122.844883));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(49.182856, -122.844883));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(49.183452, -122.846288));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(49.183761, -122.846739));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(49.184343, -122.847050));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(49.186917, -122.847061));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(49.188655, -122.847885));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(49.189560, -122.847885));
    addCircleMarker(new LatLng(49.189560, -122.847885));

    PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polyLineOptions.addAll(sourcePoints);
    polyLineOptions.width(10);
    polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
    mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);

    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sourcePoints.get(0), 15));
}
```

where:

```
public void addCircleMarker(LatLng latLng) {
    Drawable circleDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_blue_circle);
    BitmapDescriptor markerIcon = getMarkerIconFromDrawable(circleDrawable, 30, 30);

    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .icon(markerIcon)
    );
}

private BitmapDescriptor getMarkerIconFromDrawable(Drawable drawable, int width, int height) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

you got something like that:

[image: Circle markers]

and size of circles didn't change while zooming:

[image: Circle markers zoom]

Comment: But when I zoom out it becomes larger

Comment: There is no issues on my side, as you can see. Is your marker vector drawable?

Comment: as you can see in your gif circle is getting  a little bigger. I have similar issue

Comment: Hmm, seems it is the same. As I know marker icons didn't changed the size. But anyway, you can draw circle on `MapView` canvas.

Comment: I edited my question so you can see How my markers are viewed

Comment: Did you use my `ic_blue_circle.xml` or your `ic_blue_for_marker` as marker image?

Comment: I need that my icon will be same little size before and after zooming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189325/discussion-between-andrii-omelchenko-and-white).

Comment: Seems your bitmap image (`ic_blue_for_marker`) has paddings (spaces) on left and right.